# Multiple column VLOOKUP

Tags: excel-formula

I have a spreadsheet that lists all of the wines in my cellar with separate columns for the Location (1-30) and Bin (A-V) and barcode for each bottle. I want to add a sheet that creates a map of the wines with the barcode for the cell value. I could use VLOOKUP to find the location but that won't let me look up the second value. Is there a function that allows

Comment: I think you should research index match, but I can't be sure unless you have more detail about the data

Comment: Index doesn't seem to meet the need. The specifics are I have a sheet (Map) that has "Location" numbers as column headers and "Bin" letters as row indicators in column A. On another sheet (Inventory) I have entries with "Locations" (1-30) in column C and "Bin"s  (A-V) in column D. I want to create a formula that puts the value of Inventory column B into each cell where the Location and Bin from Map = the Inventory-Location and Inventory Bin. match.  The formula I used was =INDEX('Individual Bottles'!C:D,A2,B1). The formula returns #Value>

Comment: Ok. You have 2 options here... Sumproduct, else concatenate location + bin in another column and match on that.

Comment: some sample data would work wonders here.  maybe 2-3 rows of information with what sounds like 4 columns of info and then what your expected outcome is.